# Как сделать чтобы scanf игнорировал пробелы между переменными при вводе?

Tags: c

Мне нужно чтобы при вводе 3 чисел между ними и запятой можно было ставить пробелы. При этом чтобы они были integer,чтобы их было ровно 3 и чтобы при вводе числа другого формата или символа выдавало ошибку. Я написал такой код:

```
#include<stdio.h>   
int main()     
{   
    int x,y,z;
    printf("RGB: \n");
    if(scanf("%d, %d, %d", &x, &y, &z) !=3 || x>255 || x<0 || y>255 || y<0 || z>255 || z<0) {
        printf("Input Error.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("#%02X%02X%02X",x,y,z);
    return 0;
}
```

Например, если я введу: `1   ,    1  ,  1` вывод будет `Input Error` . Как мне этого избежать?
Вводя, например  `1, 1, 1` всё работает как нужно.

Появилась другая проблема. Я дополнил код:

```
#include<stdio.h>   
int main()     
{   
    int x,y,z;
    

    printf("RGB: \n");
    if(scanf("rgb(%d , %d , %d)", &x, &y, &z) !=3 || x>255 || x<0 || y>255 || y<0 || z>255 || z<0) {
        printf("Error.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("#%02X%02X%02X",x,y,z);
    return 0;
}
```

Как теперь сделать чтобы между `rgb` и скобками тоже можно было ставить пробелы? Например `rgb    (    1   ,   1 ,    1   )`

Comment: `"%d , %d , %d"`

Comment: `"rgb ( %d , %d , %d )"`